# With sed or awk, move line matching pattern to bottom of file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a similar problem.  I need to move a line in /etc/sudoers to the end of the file.

The line I am wanting to move:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I have tried with a variable

```
#creates variable value
templine=$(cat /etc/sudoers | grep "#includedir /etc/sudoers.d")

#delete value
sed '/"${templine}"/d' /etc/sudoers

#write value to the bottom of the file
cat ${templine} >> /etc/sudoers
```

Not getting any errors nor the result I am looking for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` doesn't exist in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '$0=="#includedir /etc/sudoers.d"{lastline=$0;next}{print $0}END{print lastline}' /etc/sudoers
```

That says:

1. If the line `$0` is `"#includedir /etc/sudoers.d"` then set the variable `lastline` to this line's value `$0` and skip to the next line `next`.
2. If you are still here, print the line `{print $0}`
3. Once every line in file is processed, print whatever is in the `lastline` variable.

Example:

```
$ cat test.txt
hi
this
is
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
a
test
$ awk '$0=="#includedir /etc/sudoers.d"{lastline=$0;next}{print $0}END{print lastline}' test.txt
hi
this
is
a
test
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: I am testing with a copy of /etc/sudoers and getting a result like a command has not terminated.

awk '$0=="#includedir /etc/sudoers.d"{lastline=$0;next}{print $0}END{print lastline}` /etc/sudoers

>

Comment: My apologies. I have updated the answer. I put a backtick in place of the single quote. That's been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the whole thing with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/#includedir .etc.sudoers.d/ { h; $p; d; }' -e '$G' /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: This leaves a blank line where the `#includedir` was; to avoid that, use `{h;d;}` instead of `x`.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: good point, and include `$p` to also work when the pattern is on the last line

Comment: This may reduce the file if the regexp matches more than once and only move the latest match.

Comment: @potong: true, but given the pattern that is a desirable trait here

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/regexp/H;//!p;$x;$s/.//p' file
```

This removes line(s) containing a specified regexp and appends them to the end of the file.

To only move the first line that matches the regexp, use:

```
sed -n '/regexp/{h;$p;$b;:a;n;p;$!ba;x};p' file
```

This uses a loop to read/print the remainder of the file and then append the matched line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple entries which you want to move to the end of the file, you can do the following:

```
awk '/regex/{a[++c]=$0;next}1;END{for(i=1;i<=c;++i) print a[i]}' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/regex/!{p;ba};H;:a;${x;s/.//;p}' file
```